# How to return a string in a C function?

Tags: c

I have to make a function that has a float as parameter, and the function will return that number in words (As a string)

i.e: function(12.0) will return twelve as a string

But I have some problems returning the string, it returns some weird data, I have this code:

```
            char* function (float number)
            {
                char str[] = "test";
                strcat(str, " char");
                return str;
            }

            int main()
            {
                char *test = function(5.0); 
                printf("Hi %s", test);
            }
```

That always returns a different thing:

```
            Hi u.ª╣D
            Hi uêõWÛ
```

I don't know how to fix it, because I really need to use strcat to do things like 'one thousand ten' saving time and lines of code, and it's not possible if I define char str as a pointer...

I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11

Thank you!

I searched a few days but noone of the answers worked with what I need, because they define the string as a pointer or use more than 1 parameter in the function (it only has to receive 1 float parameter, no more parameters are accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` is local to `function` and will be destroyed once control exits `function`.

Hence you can try as below.

```
            char* function (float number)
            {
                char *str = malloc(30);
                strcpy(str, " test");
                strcat(str, " char");
                return str;
            }

            int main()
            {
                char *test = function(5.0); 
                printf("Hi %s", test);
            }
```

Comment: Why `5.0` as an argument?

Comment: @Observer OP wants to convert float to string, He was struck with returning string from the function. I just focused on how to return string from function.

Comment: I tried your code, but it has an error: [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Muschel Are you using c++ compiler. if yes cast the `malloc` return to `char *` like this (`char *str = (char*)malloc(30)`).